# NavigationPage won't reappear

Tags: maui

(Sorry if this question is stupid or has already been asked before)

I'm pretty new to .NET MAUI and I'm trying to build an app and I have this code:

```
private async void BtnOptionsClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OptionsPage optPage = new();
    NavigationPage navPage = new(optPage)
    {
        Title = optPage.Title
    };

    navPage.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("BackButtonPlaceholder", "", async () =>
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Back button pressed");
        await Navigation.PopAsync();
    }));

    await Navigation.PushAsync(navPage);
}
```

I'm trying to add a back button for a specific page, not the MainPage

The problem is that the NavigationPage appears the first time and works, but the second time around it just doesn't show up, only the OptionsPage does

Btw it works fine on Android, just not Windows (I can't test on other platforms)

I tried using `RemovePage` instead of `PopAsync` and I tried adding the ToolbarItem in the OptionsPage class, nothing I tried works...

Comment: if you already have a `NavigationPage`, it's a little odd to push another `NavigationPage` onto the stack

Comment: Push optPage. Don’t wrap it in a second NavigationPage.

Comment: The thing is I don't have another NavigationPage, I want only the OptionsPage to have a NavigationPage but not the page it'll be called from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0) and [NavigationPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage?view=net-maui-7.0), by default a .NET MAUI project is created with a `Shell`.

- `NavigationPage` is hierarchicall (you push / pop pages on a stack), it's simpler to use and is more flexible but you have manage everything yourself (like menus for exemple).
- `Shell` is URI-based navigation (work the same as a website pages with urls like "/users/1/profile"), it comes with pre designed menu (tabs and flyout) and make it possible to navigate to absolute URL (which is not easy with NavigationPage). It is "replacing" NavigationPage since it cover a lot of use cases and remove a lot of boilerplate code related to navigation (that's why it's the default).

Since `Shell` is based on `NavigationPage` using the `NavigationPage` methods with `Shell` wont do any error, you should not mix them though (they are not meant to be used together).

If you want to use `NavigationPage` you should modify `./App.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Replace :
        // MainPage = new AppShell();
        // By this :
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }
}
```

Now you can use `Navigation.PushAsync(page);`, the `page` object should inherit `ContentPage` and not another `NavigationPage`.

If you want to keep Shell read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0) and use `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("../../route");` to navigate between page.